# How are messages sent slowly?

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

How are messages sent slowly? I am using socket.io for sending messages but my app sending messages is working very slowly it almost takes 8-10 seconds on average to send messages how can I improve its performance? I tried using use callback but still is not sending messages fast what can i do to improve its performance?

```
const { otheruser } = route.params;

const [mydata, setMyData] = useState(null);

const [userid, setUserid] = useState(null);
const [roomid, setRoomid] = useState(null);
const [chat, setChat] = useState(['']);
const [currentmessage, setCurrentmessage] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    LoadData()
}, [])


useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('receive_message', (data) => {
        LoadMessages(roomid)
    })
}, [socket])

const SortRoomId = (id1, id2) => {
    if (id1 > id2) {
        return id1 + id2
    } else {
        return id2 + id1
    }
}

const LoadData = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        const { token, user: { email } } = JSON.parse(value);
        const res = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/userdata', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email })
        });
        const { message, user } = await res.json();
        if (message === 'User Found') {
            setMyData(user);
            setUserid(user._id);
            const ChatRoomId = await SortRoomId(otheruser[0]._id, user._id);
            setRoomid(ChatRoomId);
            socket.emit('joinroom', { roomid: ChatRoomId });
            LoadMessages(ChatRoomId);
        } else {
            alert('Login Again');
            navigation.navigate('Login');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        navigation.navigate('Login');
    }
};


const SendMessage = useCallback(async () => {
    const MessageData = {
        message: currentmessage,
        RoomId: roomid,
        SenderId: userid,
        RecieverId: otheruser[0]._id
    };
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/SaveMessage', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(MessageData)
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.message === 'Message saved') {
            socket.emit('sendmessage', MessageData);
            LoadMessages(roomid);
            console.log('message sent');
            setCurrentmessage('');
        } else {
            alert('Network Error');
            setCurrentmessage('');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}, [currentmessage, roomid, userid, otheruser, socket]);

useEffect(() => {
    LoadMessages(roomid)
}, [chat])


const LoadMessages = async (ChatRoomId) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/GetMessages', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ RoomId: ChatRoomId })
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        setChat(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it that the message is *sent* slowly or does it take long to come up with the message, the sending takes no noticeable time, but it's the combined time these two takes that's long?

Comment: @VLAZ messges only

Comment: first try a simple code. like just to receive and send SMS